# Filter 2d arrays containing a 1d array inside a 3d array

Tags: arrays, numpy, filter

I have got a 3d array (an array of triangles). I would like to get the triangles (2d arrays) containing a given point (1d array).
I went through in1d, where, argwhere but I am still unsuccessfull....

For instance with :

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd

t = rd.random_sample((10,3,3))

v0 = np.array([1,2,3])

t[1,2] = v0
t[5,0] = v0 
t[8,1] = v0
```

I would like to get:

```
array([[[[[ 0.87312   ,  0.33411403,  0.56808291],
          [ 0.36769417,  0.66884858,  0.99675896],
          [ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ]],

         [[ 0.31995867,  0.58351034,  0.38731405],
          [ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ],
          [ 0.04435288,  0.96613852,  0.83228402]],

         [[ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ],
          [ 0.28647107,  0.95755263,  0.5378722 ],
          [ 0.73731078,  0.8777235 ,  0.75866665]]]])
```

to then get the set of v0 adjacent points

```
{[ 0.87312   ,  0.33411403,  0.56808291],
 [ 0.36769417,  0.66884858,  0.99675896],
 [ 0.31995867,  0.58351034,  0.38731405],
 [ 0.04435288,  0.96613852,  0.83228402],
 [ 0.28647107,  0.95755263,  0.5378722 ],
 [ 0.73731078,  0.8777235 ,  0.75866665]}
```

without looping, the array being quite big.

For instance

```
In [28]: np.in1d(v0,t[8]).all()
Out[28]: True
```

works as a test on a line, but I can't get it over the all array.
Thanks for your help.

What I mean is the vectorized equivalent to:

```
In[54]:[triangle for triangle in t if v0 in triangle ]
Out[54]: 
    [array([[ 0.87312   ,  0.33411403,  0.56808291],
            [ 0.36769417,  0.66884858,  0.99675896],
            [ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ]]),
     array([[ 0.31995867,  0.58351034,  0.38731405],
            [ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ],
            [ 0.04435288,  0.96613852,  0.83228402]]),
     array([[ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ],
            [ 0.28647107,  0.95755263,  0.5378722 ],
            [ 0.73731078,  0.8777235 ,  0.75866665]])]
```

Comment: Could you share complete working loopy code?

Comment: I mean I would like a vectorized equivalent to:    


`In[5]:[triangle for triangle in t if v0 in triangle ]`     


`Out[5]: [array([[ 0.87312   ,  0.33411403,  0.56808291],
        [ 0.36769417,  0.66884858,  0.99675896],
        [ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ]]),
       array([[ 0.31995867,  0.58351034,  0.38731405],
        [ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ],
        [ 0.04435288,  0.96613852,  0.83228402]]),
        array([[ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ],
        [ 0.28647107,  0.95755263,  0.5378722 ],
        [ 0.73731078,  0.8777235 ,  0.75866665]])]`

Comment: Please edit the question and add those codes and expected output into it. It's hard to read off comments.

Comment: `In[5]:[triangle for triangle in t if v0 in triangle ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do -

```
t[(t==v0).all(axis=-1).any(axis=-1)]
```

We are performing `ALL` and `ANY` reduction along the last axis with `axis=-1` there. First `.all(axis=-1)` looks for rows **exactly matching** the array `v0` and then the latter `.any(axis=-1)` looks for **`ANY` match** in each of the *2D* blocks. This results in a boolean array of the same length as the length of input array. So, we use the boolean array to filter out valid elements off the input array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So simple...What the -1s stand for ?

Comment: @user9258411 Added some explanation.